# Video.js and Internet Explorer - Video not playing and completely blank screen

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, video.js

I'm using video.js to play video on a website.

All works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari BUT NOT in Internet Explorer.
I just get a black rectangle on screen, no poster image, no video controls and no video.

I am providing video in three different formats: mp4, webm and ogv

You can see this here - http://demo.clarkedesign.co.uk/video-js/

Please can any one help to get the poster image displayed AND get the video controls to display and the video to play in IE?

Comment: I'm facing same problem. No error coming, but not playing video. Only playing in IE 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked your demo with Internet Explorer 7-9. For me, it works without any problems in all these versions of IE. The poster image is displayed as well as the video controls and the video itself.

Are you sure you don't have Javascript disabled in the security settings?